# Android crashes with OutOfMemoryError

Tags: android

I have an activity with some pictures in it. I've tried to launch that activity in my phone when it stopped working. All of my pictures are 634x561 size. I've found that I can have maximum 6 pictures without my phone crashing. When I reduce images to 100x88 the app works fine even with 12 images, but I lose quality. I have to make 10 activities with a total of 306 pictures in them. Is it possible?

I tested images with various sizes and decided that size 200x177 would be the best for me. Can my phone withstand it? (I am using Samsung Galaxy S4)

Note that I don't want to use `android:largeHeap="true"` since it is said in Android developers site that it's not advisable to use it.

**Logcat:**

```
06-08 19:31:25.894    7226-7226/com.ket_taisykles.kasparas.KET_taisykles E/SELinux﹕ [DEBUG] get_category: variable seinfo: default sensitivity: NULL, cateogry: NULL
06-08 19:31:26.095    7226-7226/com.ket_taisykles.kasparas.KET_taisykles E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.ket_taisykles.kasparas.KET_taisykles, PID: 7226
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application android.app.Application: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to get package info for com.ket_taisykles.kasparas.KET_taisykles; is package not installed?
            at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:625)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5088)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:177)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1509)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5944)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1389)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1184)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to get package info for com.ket_taisykles.kasparas.KET_taisykles; is package not installed?
            at android.app.LoadedApk.initializeJavaContextClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:471)
            at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:420)
            at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:615)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5088)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:177)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1509)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5944)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1389)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1184)
06-08 19:31:36.315    7456-7456/com.ket_taisykles.kasparas.KET_taisykles E/libEGL﹕ call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)
06-08 19:32:37.334    8482-8482/com.ket_taisykles.kasparas.KET_taisykles E/Zygote﹕ MountEmulatedStorage()
06-08 19:32:37.334    8482-8482/com.ket_taisykles.kasparas.KET_taisykles E/Zygote﹕ v2
06-08 19:32:37.404    8482-8482/com.ket_taisykles.kasparas.KET_taisykles E/SELinux﹕ [DEBUG] get_category: variable seinfo: default sensitivity: NULL, cateogry: NULL
06-08 19:32:42.940    8482-8498/com.ket_taisykles.kasparas.KET_taisykles W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 41.717ms
06-08 19:32:43.790    8482-8482/com.ket_taisykles.kasparas.KET_taisykles E/art﹕ Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 316812 byte allocation with 120176 free bytes and 117KB until OOM"
06-08 19:32:43.800    8482-8482/com.ket_taisykles.kasparas.KET_taisykles E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.ket_taisykles.kasparas.KET_taisykles, PID: 8482
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ket_taisykles.kasparas.KET_taisykles/com.ket_taisykles.kasparas.KET_taisykles.ispejamiejiZenklai1}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #624: Error inflating class <unknown>
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2693)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2760)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1448)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5944)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1389)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1184)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #624: Error inflating class <unknown>
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:640)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:689)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:748)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:821)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:228)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:102)
            at com.ket_taisykles.kasparas.KET_taisykles.ispejamiejiZenklai1.onCreate(ispejamiejiZenklai1.java:15)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6289)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2760)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1448)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5944)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1389)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1184)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:614)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:689)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:748)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:821)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:228)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:102)
            at com.ket_taisykles.kasparas.KET_taisykles.ispejamiejiZenklai1.onCreate(ispejamiejiZenklai1.java:15)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6289)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2760)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1448)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5944)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1389)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1184)
     Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 316812 byte allocation with 120176 free bytes and 117KB until OOM
            at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:726)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:547)
            at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1014)
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:3730)
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3603)
            at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:762)
            at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:151)
            at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:140)
            at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:136)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:614)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:689)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:748)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:821)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:228)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:102)
            at com.ket_taisykles.kasparas.KET_taisykles.ispejamiejiZenklai1.onCreate(ispejamiejiZenklai1.java:15)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6289)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2760)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1448)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5944)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1389)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1184)
```

**One of my images in XML:**

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:src="@drawable/z_101"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:maxWidth="100dp"
        android:maxHeight="100dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView103"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

Comment: Handling bitmaps is a highly memory-heavy tasks. I'd suggest caching those images or saving them directly to the disk. Are you getting images from the web?

Comment: No, they are in my drawable folder.

Comment: We cannot say much as you are not telling where you display the images. And you have a terrible lot of different exceptions. What are you doing against them?

Comment: On what kind of screen can you display six pictures of 634x561?

Comment: Their sizes are reduced. Look in my xml code: android:maxWidth="100dp"
        android:maxHeight="100dp"

Comment: I've inserted 95 pictures into my app and android studio freezes every time I want to edit the activity with the pictures. My phone however works fine and displays all pictures without lagging. I guess I'll have to shrink the images to 100x88.